# Query Django Wagtail Document Model

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I have a client that has hundreds of documents that are tagged that we need to query and list on a page.  I want to write a TemplateTag so its more reusable, but I have no idea how to query the builtin Wagtail image and document models.  The below code is what I am starting with `Document.objects.all()` added for placement only. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@register.inclusion_tag(
    'tags/_document_snippets.html', takes_context=True
)
def document_snippets(context):
    documents = Documents.objects.all()
    return {
        'documents': documents,
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I thought I would answer my own question for the benefit of others.

**import get_document_model**

```
from wagtail.wagtaildocs.models import get_document_model
```

**create tag**

```
@register.inclusion_tag(
    'tags/_documents_snippets.html',
    takes_context=True
)
def document_snippets(context):
    Document = get_document_model()
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return {
        'documents': documents,
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

**add to template**

```
{% for doc in documents %}
    <a href="{{ doc.url }}">{{ doc.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: After the Wagtail 2.0 release, a lot of import statements have changed.  The import statement would now be: from wagtail.documents.models import get_document_model.